# angularjs deferred.reject() not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using firebase with angularjs. I want to defer `FirebaseAuthClient` callback.
Everything work fine but just the reject is not working if added.
please see my snippet code.

**In factory**

```
    auth.callback = function(error, user) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if (user) {
            deferred.resolve(user);
        } else if (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        } else {
            //QUESTION HERE, if this line is added, the promise 
            //will not working at all means function inside 
            //.then() will not trigger. If I comment it out
            //Everything work fine, but how can I know if use logout ?
            deferred.reject(); 
        }

    }, 0);
    return deferred.promise;
}

auth.firebaseAuthClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
    auth.callback(error, user);
});
```

**In .run()**

```
    firebaseAuth.callback().then(function(success){
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
    }, function(fail) {
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    })
```

Comment: where you have defined deferred ?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal just snippet code. I defined at top, var deferred = $q.defer();

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return $q.reject(reason) code within failure callback of then function call.

It is covered in the [$q angularjs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Comment: Hi, Charles, I don't get it. I added `deferred.reject('user not login')`. Then I test `console.log()` in `.then()` function but it return user not log which I confirm that user is already logged-in.

Comment: I don't see it either, isn't the second callback function in `then()` the failure callback function?

Comment: this did not fix it for me either. can someone post a jsfiddle of reject() working... (stopping execution of the following then())